# How do I access UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey from applicationWillEnterForeground?

Tags: ios

Imagine my surprise when I discovered that there is no applicationWillEnterForegroundWithOptions api!

I have an app which exports a custom UTI. When I get an email containing an attachment, holding on the attachment dutifully brings up the Open In MyApp option. Pressing it, as expected opens (or activates) MyApp. This is all well and good if my app wasn't in the background because I can retrieve the file URL from the launch options passed to didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.

What if my app is in the background though. Pressing the Open In button brings my app to the foreground by calling applicationWillEnterForeground, but without a userInfo dictionary, how do I get at the URL with which my app was activated?

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `UIApplicationDelegate` method `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:` is called when your app is launched to open a URL. This is true whether your app is newly launched or simply brought to the foreground.

It is this method (and not the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method) that you should process the URL.

Comment: The only problem with this is that openURL is called AFTER didFinishLaunchingWithOptions and applicationWillEnterForeground methods...so neither method knows what opens there are. You must do what you need to do in the openURL method and store items that you may need (variable, etc) in standardUserDefaults or something like that before you get to openURL...